# How to put a quote inbetwen two bullet points?

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to post Angular brackets in code?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1993/how-to-post-angular-brackets-in-code)

When you have a quote in between two bullet points, the markup after that goes haywire.
Example:

1. This is the first point. Note that it is shown as 1, as expected.

> This is a quote.

2. This is the second point. Note that it is shown as 1, even though 2 is entered in the markup code.

This is the image of the code that created the post:
[image]